# Whats the reason why MS Teams activity (done via the API) does not show up in the Teams Report?

Tags: microsoft-teams

i have noticed the following today and i'm not sure if this works as designed:

If you use one of the beta graph apis to send messages/replies to  teams then this activity does not appear at all in the out of the box Teams User activity reports (o365 admin portal)

...i have no idea why this is not counted......i use delegated permission here to push content to a team

e.g this is one of the apis i'm using

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-chatmessage?view=graph-rest-beta

Is this intented ?

Comment: Could you please confirm if other members who are following this channel are getting the activity feed notification? You as a sending won't be getting notification in your own activity feed. I just tried this and other members are getting notified as expeced.